# How to retrieve all open sockets with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have created a demo project to implement websocket via socket.io following the documentation. However, when I try to fetch all open sockets from the server using `fetchSockets()` function mentioned in the docs https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#serverfetchsockets, the webserver crashes and I recieve error message `TypeError: io.fetchSockets is not a function`.

##### Server side code

```js
const express = require("express");
const Server = require("socket.io");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

const webserver = app.listen(9001, () => {
  console.log("Running on port 9001");
});

const io = new Server(webserver);

io.on("connect", async (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id + "client connected!");
  
  // Fetch open sockets and log them
  const sockets = await io.fetchSockets();
  console.log(sockets);
});
```

##### My client side code in html page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    const socket = io("http://localhost:9001");

    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("connected!");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

##### The Error message returned

```bash
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Running on port 9001
GkBIw5SD_7qGcDxJAAAAclient connected!
/home/euna/sandbox/testsockets/index.js:18
  const sockets = await io.fetchSockets();
                           ^
TypeError: io.fetchSockets is not a function
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (/home/euna/sandbox/testsockets/index.js:18:28)
    at Namespace.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Namespace.emit (/home/euna/sandbox/testsockets/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:209:10)
    at /home/euna/sandbox/testsockets/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:176:14
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

Node.js v18.17.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: socketio version ?

Comment: If `io.fetchSockets is not a function` is not a function, then it seems likely you are not running the v4 version of socket.io on your client and server as this function was introduced in v4.

Comment: It was version 1, when I upgraded to version 4 it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment `io.fetchSockets()` was introduced in socket.io version 4 so you need to upgrade both client and server to v4.

The only other way you could get that error (even when running socket.io v4) is if `io` isn't what you actually think it is.  But, the code as you show in your question it has a proper value for `io` and it's declared `const` so it isn't likely that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade socket.io to version 4

```bash
npm un socketio
npm i socket.io
```